# how to text field visibility show click on alert dialog button in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want when I click the OK button of the alert dialog box, then show textfield visibility (this textfield is given below of the "Open dialog" button, and this textfield visibility is by default hide). but it's not happening I don't understand what is the mistake here.

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
void main()=> runApp(MyHomePages());
class MyHomePages  extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "KYC Formm",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: MyHomePageDesign(title: "Kyc form"),
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePageDesign extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePageDesign({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePageDesign> {
  bool _isVisible = false ;
  bool  _isRcVisible = false;
  String textRcValue;
  TextEditingController _textFieldControllerD = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _textRcFieldController = TextEditingController();
  void _displayDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          // this was required, rest is same
          return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, setState){
                return AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('Choose any one'),
                    content: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text("Capture Photo",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0,),),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text("Pick Photo",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0,),),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: (){
                                setState(() => _isVisible = !_isVisible);
                              },
                              child: Text("Enter RC Number",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,),),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                          Visibility(
                            visible: _isVisible,
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Container(
                                width: 200.0,
                                height: 60.0,
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 0.0,bottom: 10.0,right: 0.0),
                                child: TextField(
                                  controller: _textFieldControllerD,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                    labelText: 'Enter RC No',
                                  ),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    fontSize: 18.0,),),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            child: new FlatButton(
                              child: new Text('OK',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.teal
                                ),),
                              onPressed: () {
                                textRcValue= _textFieldControllerD.text;
                                setState(() {
                                  _isRcVisible = true;
                                });
                                _textRcFieldController.text=  textRcValue;
                                print("RcValue:");
                                print(textRcValue);
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                            ),
                          )
                        ]
                    )
                );
              }
          );
        });
   }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child:Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 160.0,
              height: 50.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, left: 5.0,bottom: 10.0,right: 0.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Text('Open Dialog'),
                onPressed: () {
                  _displayDialog(context);
                },
              ),

            ),
            Visibility(
              visible: _isRcVisible,
              child: TextField(
                controller: _textRcFieldController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter Rc Number"),
                onTap: (){},
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `setState` you're calling in the dialog to make the `isRcVisible` true to a function call in the `State` of your main widget.

```
_setRcVisible() { // this is new
    this.setState(() {
      _isRcVisible = true;
    });
  }

  void _displayDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          // this was required, rest is same
          return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, setState){
                return AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('Choose any one'),
                    content: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text("Capture Photo",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0,),),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text("Pick Photo",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0,),),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: (){
                                setState(() => _isVisible = !_isVisible);
                              },
                              child: Text("Enter RC Number",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,),),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                          Visibility(
                            visible: _isVisible,
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Container(
                                width: 200.0,
                                height: 60.0,
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 0.0,bottom: 10.0,right: 0.0),
                                child: TextField(
                                  controller: _textFieldControllerD,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                    labelText: 'Enter RC No',
                                  ),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    fontSize: 18.0,),),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            child: new FlatButton(
                              child: new Text('OK',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.teal
                                ),),
                              onPressed: () {
                                textRcValue= _textFieldControllerD.text;
                                _setRcVisible(); // this is new
                                _textRcFieldController.text=  textRcValue;
                                print("RcValue:");
                                print(textRcValue);
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                            ),
                          )
                        ]
                    )
                );
              }
          );
        });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me a reply. this answer  is helpful for me